# jquery setTimeout inside each

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each, arrayiterator

i have some code similar to this, that moves inside some images... it works but it doesn't seem to respect timer

```
var i = 1;
var indexArray = array(1,2,3);
var timerx = new Array();

$( indexArray ).each(function( indexArraykey ) {

    function internalCallback ( i, indexArraykey ) {
        val = indexArray[indexArraykey];
        console.log("test " + i + val);
    }); 

    timerx[i] = setTimeout( internalCallback( i, indexArraykey ), i * 500000 );                     

    i++;

});
```

Comment: Why would you define a function in a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points :

- `i` has the value of end of loop by the time the callback is called.
- to iterate over an array using jQuery, use `$.each(array,`, not `$(array).each(`
- the function doesn't have to be defined in the loop
- each gives the index as second argument of the callback and as first argument the value.

So it seems that what you want is in fact this :

```
var indexArray = array(1,2,3);
var timerx = [];
$.each(indexArray, function( indexArrayValue, i ) {
    timerx.push(setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("test " + i + ' : ' + indexArrayValue);
    }, (i+1) * 500000));
});
```

Comment: Using `});` to end `internalCallback` is wrong. =) Would result in syntax error.

Comment: sorry is a typo, the code works. i try to modify and it dosen't work, but in log the number is correct

Comment: In fact, you changed the code after my first answer. I now think that what you really want is the new code at the end of my function.

Answer (score 1):

That is so poor design, no but a total anti js pattern even beyond...
Why would you define the same function over and over again!!!

```
$(imgNumArray).each(function (indexArraykey) {
    (function (i) {
        timerx[i] = setTimeout(internalCallback(i, indexArraykey), i * 500000);
    })(i++);
});

function internalCallback(i, indexArraykey) {
    val = indexArray[indexArraykey];
    console.log("test " + i + val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not javascript expert, but looks like here `internalCallback` is getting called instead of being passed as function to `setTimeout`.

Try this:

```
var i = 1;
var indexArray = [3,6,9];
var timerx = new Array();

$( indexArray ).each(function( indexArraykey ) {

    function internalCallback ( i, indexArraykey ) {
        return function () {
            val = indexArray[indexArraykey];
            console.log("test " + i + val);
        }
    } 

    timerx[i] = setTimeout( internalCallback( i, indexArraykey ), i * 5000);                     

    i++;

});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Guxdz/2/ (check the console log)

Comment: +1 thanks to you too, even if is not really clear to me why :-)