# Jquery loop through array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

This question has been asked many times, but as a beginner, it's hard for me to apply other peoples scripts to my own assigned classes and vars.

What I would like to know is:

I have a simple area in the html that looks like this:

```
<h1>I like: <span class ="hobbies">array items go here</span></h1>
```

I've made an array as such:

```
var hobbies=new Array("graphic design.","photography.", "videography.", "marketing.", "craft beers.")
```

I want each item to appear by itself for say 3 seconds or so then fade out and get replaced by the next item in the array.  I would also like for this to loop once it has finished going through all the options.  How could I do something like this?

I also have:

```
$('.hobbies').html(hobbies);
```

Thanks in advance for reading through!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573859/jquery-settimeout-inside-each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're going to have to use a `setInterval` to repeat the function at specific time delays.

Save an index of the current position in the hobbies array and on each iteration increase the index. Make sure to reset the index when it reaches the same value as your arrays length.

```
// Always a good idea to cache selectors you're gonna be using alot.
var hobbyContainer = $('.hobby');
hobbyContainer.text(hobbies[0]);
var index = 1;
setInterval(function(){
  hobbyContainer.fadeOut('fast',function(){
    hobbyContainer.text(hobbies[index]);
    index++;
    if (index >= hobbies.length){
      index = 0;
    }
  }).fadeIn('fast');
},3000);
```

You might have to play with the duration of the interval in order to leave time for the fading animation. Or you could make the fade animation faster as I have done in my example.

#### [Here is a simple demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WXW78/2/)

Comment: I think it should be index >= hobbies.length or index == hobbies.length

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
    var hobbies = //"yourarray";
    var count = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        scrollText(hobbies[count]);
        count++;
        if (count == hobbies.length ) {
            count = 0;
        }
    }, 3000);


function scrollText(text) {     
    $(".hobbies").animate({opacity:0},function(){
        $(this).html(text).animate({opacity:1});  
    });
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/DUVes/)**